# How to change Bootstrap 5 Dropdown menu hover color?

Tags: html, css, web, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I've been trying to change the hover color for a dropdown menu in Bootstrap 5. But I don't know how I should do it.
In the end it should look like this:

[image: so1]

But currently it looks like this:

[image: so2]

Sorry, forgot about the Code:
Index.html
https://wtools.io/paste-code/b9c2

css:
https://wtools.io/paste-code/b9c3

Comment: And where is your code? We can‘t help without your code…

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement.

Comment: Are you familiar with basic CSS principles?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Please enter your code here to receive assistance.

```css
.dropdown a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out;
    background-color: grey;
}

.dropdown a:hover {

    color: red;
    background-color:green;

}
```

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```